# How to combine month and Year selected from diffrent Dropdowns and save in table in datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net

..............aspx page code.................

```
<tr>
    <td>
        From Date
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpFromMonth" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:DropDownList ID="drpFromYear" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
   </td>
   <td>
       To Date
   </td>
   <td>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="drpToMonth" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:DropDownList ID="drpToYear" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
   </td>
</tr>
```

.........aspx.cs code........

//This is for populate dropdown.

```
private void PopulateFromMonth() // Populate Month ... e.g. Jan
{
    try
    {
        Generic mGn = GenericBusiness<object>.GetGeneralList("Month");
        drpFromYear.DataSource = mGn.Result;
        drpFromYear.DataTextField = "ListItemName"; // Jan, Feb, etc ....
        drpFromYear.DataValueField = "ListItemValue"; // 1,2,3, etc ....
        drpFromYear.DataBind();
        drpFromYear.Items.Insert(0, GlobalValues.DRPSELECT);
        drpFromYear.Items[0].Value = "0";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void PopulateToMonth() // Populate Month ... e.g. Jan

{
    try
    {
        Generic mGn = GenericBusiness<object>.GetGeneralList("Month");
        drpFromYear.DataSource = mGn.Result;
        drpFromYear.DataTextField = "ListItemName"; // Jan, Feb, etc ....
        drpFromYear.DataValueField = "ListItemValue"; // 1,2,3, etc ....
        drpFromYear.DataBind();
        drpFromYear.Items.Insert(0, GlobalValues.DRPSELECT);
        drpFromYear.Items[0].Value = "0";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void PopulateFromYear() // Populate Year ... e.g. 2008, 2009, 2010
{
    try
    {
        Generic mGn = GenericBusiness<object>.GetGeneralList("PMSYear");
        drpFromYear.DataSource = mGn.Result;
        drpFromYear.DataTextField = "ListItemName"; // 2008,2009,2010, etc ....
        drpFromYear.DataValueField = "ListItemValue"; // 8,9,10, etc ....
        drpFromYear.DataBind();
        drpFromYear.Items.Insert(0, GlobalValues.DRPSELECT);
        drpFromYear.Items[0].Value = "0";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

private void PopulateToYear() // Populate Year ... e.g. 2008, 2009, 2010
{
    try
    {
        Generic mGn = GenericBusiness<object>.GetGeneralList("PMSYear");
        drpToYear.DataSource = mGn.Result;
        drpToYear.DataTextField = "ListItemName"; // 2008,2009,2010, etc ....
        drpToYear.DataValueField = "ListItemValue"; // 8,9,10, etc ....
        drpToYear.DataBind();
        drpToYear.Items.Insert(0, GlobalValues.DRPSELECT);
        drpToYear.Items[0].Value = "0";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

public void btnAdd_Click(...)
{
   dr.FromDate = ?
   dr.ToDate = ?
}

Please help me out how it is possible to assign proper date time to dr.FromDate & dr.ToDate

Comment: Your "ToMonth" is setting the FromYear by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to assume your PopulateToMonth dropdown list was a typo and that it is infact drpFromMonth.

```
DateTime dateSelected = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0}/1/{1}", drpFromMonth.SelectedItem.Value, drpFromYear.SelectedItem.Value));
```

As always, validate first that your dropdowns actually have a selected value.

Comment: I know i'm not showing you the From Month to Month, but you get the picture from the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the DateTime constructor that takes year, month and day.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x.aspx

Just pass in the year and month values and you can set day to 1 or whatever makes sense to you.